# Почему некорректно работает парсинг даты?

Tags: java, дата

```
 private void setBirthDate (String birthDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("DD-MM-YYYY");
        try {
            dateOfBirth = df.parse (birthDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new InputMismatchException ();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С маленько буквы год и день:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Дока по [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).